Fedora 40 crash when booting
When I tried to boot Fedora, it stuck at here.
I've waited for about 5 minutes . It only takes me 10 seconds to boot it in the past. 
What happend and how can I fix it?

Try holding Shift key. Are you able to enter GRUB? If so, edit the command line and remove quiet splash, these two are making you blind. Then re-post where it got stuck in high resolution please.

Now I can see the error message, but I don't know how to solve the problem. I've edited the question and added the screenshot

Looks like a disk error. Might be fixable.

Please go to GRUB again, there shall be a possibility of running commands (limited).

Run: fsck.btrfs -fy /dev/sda3

OK. Now I've entered the GRUB command line.

It says "can't find command 'fsck.btrfs'". I 've also tried "fsck" but got the same result.

Ah, my limited knowledge of grub ends here. Please boot any Live distro and run that command from there.

Your BTRFS FS is damaged. Boot in safe mode, run fsck on it.

@VlastimilBurián fsck.btrfs doesn't actually do anything, see its manpage. Gordon needs to run btrfs check /dev/sdb3, hoping that the rescue initrd contains the btrfs tool.

Thanks for your help. But I can't find fsck or btrfs command.

@MarcusMüller Okay, new intel, thanks. I don't use BTRFS, good old Ext4 so far. Cheers.

@VlastimilBurián it's the stability of drivers that is illustrated here that keeps me from it, as well.

@GordonZhang Please, use Marcus' wisdom, I don't know much about BTRFS.

@MarcusMüller
Thank you for your help. However, "btrfs check "doesn't work. I'll install Fedora again.

@GordonZhang Maybe you have disk error, failing drive... I suggest checking SMART and monitoring dmesg may be helpful.

Thanks. I'll try to use these things and be more careful when using my new fedora.
